# Will you stay or will you go?

Tags: riddle

> Oh how you need me to do day-to-day activities,
>   I sit here waiting with my fellows, for you to come. 
>   You wish to get me,
>   Taking time to wait and find me,
>   You may even wait for one to leave me so you can take me for yourself.
>   Only to leave me the minute you get me.
>   You leave me for hours a day.
>   Then suddenly when you are ready to come back,
>   You are reunited with me and the thing you left.
>   You then take that thing and leave once more,
>   Just to do the same thing again.

Comment: Should I stay or should i go? (djent,djent,djent,  -  djent,djent,djent,djent,djent,) Now your head is playing that music :)

Comment: Lunch Lady, Lunch Lady.  Wherefore art thou Lunch Lady.  My tray be empty, but my heart be full.  Full!  Full of the love I have for you and your mashed potatoes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are

> a parking space.

Oh how you need me to do day-to-day activities,

> Barring other forms of transportation, parking spaces are necessary for driving.

I sit here waiting with my fellows, for you to come.

> Parking spaces are grouped together.

You wish to get me,
Taking time to wait and find me,
You may even wait for one to leave me so you can take me for yourself.

> In parking lots, finding a parking space sometimes requires circling around, waiting for someone to leave.

Only to leave me the minute you get me.
You leave me for hours a day.

> When you take a parking space, you leave immediately, possibly for hours.

Then suddenly when you are ready to come back,
You are reunited with me and the thing you left.
You then take that thing and leave once more,
Just to do the same thing again.

> You return to your car and drive it away, parking it in another parking space.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. The check will come soon :D

Answer (score 14):

Perhaps you are a...

> Toilet

TITLE: Will you stay or will you go?

> Will you "go"

Oh how you need me to do day-to-day activities,

> Self-explanatory

I sit here waiting with my fellows, for you to come.

> In a bathroom, there are often several other toilets, referred to as "fellows."

You wish to get me,

> You want to get an available stall.

Taking time to wait and find me,

> Sometimes there's a line, sometimes you need to wait for an appropriate time, and sometimes you don't know where the bathroom is in an unfamiliar building.

You may even wait for one to leave me so you can take me for yourself.

> Wait for someone to leave a stall, so it's available.

Only to leave me the minute you get me.

> You usually don't stay for very long.

You leave me for hours a day.

> You can often go hours without going to the bathroom.

Then suddenly when you are ready to come back / You are reunited with me and the thing you left.

> Perhaps the "thing you left" could be toilet paper.

You then take that thing and leave once more,

> You take more toilet paper and leave it behind once again?

Just to do the same thing again.

> You use the bathroom several times throughout the day.

Comment: Very good answer, and I did not expect anything to fit as well as this, other than the correct answer! Definitely +1, but this is not correct.

Comment: I was thinking this too :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm only seeing this now, and while I know it's not the right answer, I couldn't get this one out of my head..

> A Bed pillow

TITLE: Will you stay or will you go?

> Every Morning impossible (for me) to get out @! :D

Oh how you need me to do day-to-day activities,

> We need sleep daily.

I sit here waiting with my fellows, for you to come.

> More than 1 pillow per bed

You wish to get me,

> You can't fight a sleep.

Taking time to wait and find me,

> Could only think of a check-in time for a hotel here ?.

You may even wait for one to leave me so you can take me for yourself.

> Stealing someone elses bed?!

Only to leave me the minute you get me.

> This is the biggest stretch but maybe when you lose consciousness for sleep

You leave me for hours a day.

> Sleep ?

Then suddenly when you are ready to come back / You are reunited with me and the thing you left.

> Back from your dreams ?.

You then take that thing and leave once more,

> Out to work, or out of bed!

Just to do the same thing again.

> Everyday you sleep .

Comment: I like the creativity! :D